# Detect browser and version - no Modernizr

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, browser, user-agent

I need for specific reasons precisely detect browser name and version. Searched here and rest of the web and most answers point to Modernizr and detecting features. That's not what I want. I want to get actual name and version.

That means:

- if it's Edge, I need to know it's version, not it's EdgeHTML version (optional, but it would be great if I can get that data)
- if it's let's say Vivaldi, then don't tell me it's Safari or Chrome, it's Vivaldi.
- if it is some browser I haven't heard of and is not listed in my list that I search for in user agent, I need to know it's name (and version).

I tried with .NET with both mixture of **userAgent** data and **HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser** class (and even taking in consideration the operating system).
However, it sends ambiguous data, once in a while doesn't recognize Chrome.

Possible solution can be JS/jQuery, it doesn't have to be .NET.

EDIT:
Someone said that this is possible duplication: [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)
It is not, because I tested it against Vivaldi

(user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.189 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.95.1077.60)

and it outputted Chrome 64, so it doesn't meet my criteria stated above

Comment: Usually I use `Navigator` API for getting browser information, I make ajax call to server with required data from `Navigator` and in server you can read those. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: i don't think modernizr supports this [feature](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/203)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: Show https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435511/why-using-window-navigator-useragent-to-retrieve-the-browser-explorer-11-is-reco

Comment: @IteratioN7T No, it's not a duplicate, see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

Since the `navigator.userAgent` string can be a bit funky at times, I typically rely on a library like [useragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/useragent) to parse it for me.

If you're not looking to add another dependency, you could at least use that as a jumping-off point for understanding how to better parse the `userAgent` string.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

jQuery.browser and  jQuery.browser.version

the full answer is here:
[How to get browser's name client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489546/how-to-get-browsers-name-client-side)

hope it helps ;)